# Tilestache Vector Tiles with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, tilestache, vector-tiles

I've set up a tilestache server and I am displaying vector tiles from the service using leaflet and the leaflet-tilelayer-geojson script from:

https://github.com/glenrobertson/leaflet-tilelayer-geojson

This works great but the sample code displays all polygons using the same style.  I would like to display a different style (polygon fill color) for each polygon based on a field attribute.  Not totally sure how to do this on the geometryCollection that is created using leaflet-tilelayer-geojson javascript.  It would seem I need to create a style function but not sure how to do this on the geometryCollection.